# Show modal bootstrap with optional value from javascript with single quote

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, quotes

Modal can't be displayed because there is value single quote (') javascript:edit in variable three. please resolve this problem...

I've been using htmlspecial character in javascript function, but still no effect in single quotes.

thanks before -_-.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="mEditComment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit comment</h4>
      </div>
      <br>

      <form name="editCmmt" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
        <fieldset>

          <div class="control-group">
            <!-- nama -->
            <label class="control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="email" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <!-- nama -->
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="email" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <!-- asal-->
            <label class="control-label">Komentar</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="text" name="comment" class="input-xlarge">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <input type="submit" name="edit" class="btn btn-success" value="Update">
          <input type="reset" name="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="reset">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  //open modal dialog for edit
  function edit(satu, dua, tiga) {
      document.editCmmt.email.value = satu;
      document.editCmmt.name.value = dua;
      document.editCmmt.komentar.value = tiga;
      $('#mEditComment').modal('show');
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:edit('bagus@domain.com','Bagus Wicaksono','the prob'lem was here')" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Edit comment</a>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Why do you need the single quote where you have it?

Comment: I writing javascript: edit () dynamically from databases. Can you provide feedback?

Comment: Septian, how are you writing it dynamically, what language are you using?

Comment: `\'` Escape the quotes.

Comment: thanks for all the attention and your answer friends. b2238488 , I am from Indonesia, sorry if my english bad. Michael , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply escape the single quote with `\`

```html
<a href="#"
  onclick="javascript:edit('bagus@domain.com','Bagus Wicaksono','the prob\'lem was here')"
  data-toggle="modal"
  class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
  Edit comment</a>
```

and it'll work. This tells the parser that you want a literal `'` to be inserted into the string.

Comment: Thanks, It's work. Is there any php function to insert the character "\" before the single quote?